# Removing default CSS classes from form using preprocess

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have a custom Form API and I'm trying to render it in `my-form-form.html.twig` file. When I print out the fields fe. {{form.name}} it still has default CSS from base theme.

How can I remove those classes from all the `elements`, `labels` , `inputs` etc using mymodule_form_alter or hook_preprocess?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, you can use hook form alter in your module:

```
// remove html class from form item
function your_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'form_id':
      $classes = &$form['actions']['item_name']['#attributes']['class'];
      $classes = array_filter($classes , function($e){
        return $e != 'class_to_remove';
      });
    break;
  }   
}
```

I don't know if answering here is valid, but I've found this answer on drupal.org https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2017-11-13/drupal-8-how-to-remove-class-of-form

There's also drupal.stackexchange.com and you are also welcome there.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that code too, but the point is it also generates unwanted div's in fieldset for example, <legend> tags and etc. The code you gave me removes classes from button , but I need code  for every element in the form so I don't have to preprocess every element ...

Comment: There is a good article that shows how to deal with updating form https://www.foreach.be/blog/how-manipulate-forms-drupal-8  , you'll end up with services, yml and templates